# How to commit offset in kafka in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My problem is I want to read message from the smallest offset of Kafka, in Apache Spark. After that I'll close the program,And will restart the program It should be start from where I was closed the program.
But as per defined configuration in [enter link description here](https://github.com/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer)

no offset is saving under the zookeeper.

Comment: Think about Kafka as just a store of (offset, message) pairs. It's up to you of bookmarking which messages you've read, so store offsets of messages you've processed in e.g. Zookeeper, db, flat file etc., and read from particular offset in startup of your app.
Kafka is store not only for you app.